# Image not showing data-bg-src

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to display an image using the following code

```
<span class="wvc-ils-item-title">Marketing</span></a></li><li data-bg-src="//****.co.uk/wp-content/Dropper-Bottle-PNG.png" data-bg-atts="{&quot;background_type&quot;:&quot;image&quot;,&quot;background_color&quot;:&quot;default&quot;,&quot;background_img&quot;:&quot;4628&quot;,&quot;background_position&quot;:&quot;center center&quot;,&quot;background_repeat&quot;:&quot;no-repeat&quot;,&quot;background_size&quot;:&quot;cover&quot;,&quot;overlay_color&quot;:&quot;black&quot;,&quot;overlay_opacity&quot;:60}"
```

The image is saved in the correct place on the hosting side - in the correct folder with the correct file name and **it still is not displaying**

Any suggestions?

Comment: Check browser console for 404 error, and make sure the image is properly loading

Comment: how would I apply the data-bg-atts once I have changed to img src

Comment: Why would data-bg-src ever display an image? And you can't use img src on li. You need to set the background-img in css.

Answer (score 0):

`data-bg-src` itself can't show an image in HTML. You must declare an `<img>` then from javascript code you can store `data-bg-src` attribute and set the `<img>`'s src attribute to `data-bg-src`